# Django Admin with custom form; calculate field not in form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In a normal (none admin view), if one has a field that is calculated by the backend, and not in the form, one would handle it like so:

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.calc_me = calc_at_now()
obj.save
```

Now say I have an admin model for Foo

```
@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['calc_me']
```

How do I tell Django that when it saves `Foo`, to calculate the required field with `obj.calc_me = calc_at_now()` ?

In `BaseModelAdmin` I see there is a method:

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Given a model instance save it to the database.
        """
        obj.save()
```

Is it not a bit hacky to override this function since its not documented?

Or how about override the models clean method?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def clean(self):        
        self.calc_me = calc_at_now()
        super().clean()
```

What is the recommended approach. Trying to start using forms the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using either a pre_save or post_save signal instead, unless your scenario only applies to the admin page.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I try to only use signals when I am really in a pickle. My research has shown that signals can sometimes be an anti pattern.

Comment: In that case, you could override the save method on the model, as suggested above

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding save method in your model
like

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calc_me = calc_at_now()
        super(Collector, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

lets give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can override **save_model()** in your admin class and save any model field.

```
@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        # save any field value
        obj.calc_me = calc_at_now()

        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

you can also differentiate add form and change form with **change** flag in save_model().